# SQL or statement vs multiple select queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm having a table with an id and a name.
I'm getting a list of id's and i need their names.

In my knowledge i have two options.

Create a forloop in my code which executes:

```
SELECT name from table where id=x
```

where x is always a number.

or I'm write a single query like this:

```
SELECT name from table where id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3
```

The list of id's and names is enormous so i think you wouldn't want that.
The problem of id's is the **id is not always a number** but a random generated id containting numbers and characters. So talking about **ranges** is not a solution.

I'm asking this in a performance point of view.

What's a nice solution for this problem?

Comment: What are your considerations? Do you need to put this as part of some code in another application? Are you talking merely about ease of use? Performance??  Also, why not use the IN operator??  (meaning, FROM table WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7......) ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite has [limits](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/limit.html) on the size of a query, so if there is no known upper limit on the number of IDs, you cannot use a single query.

When you are reading multiple rows (note: `IN (1, 2, 3)` is easier than many ORs), you don't know to which ID a name belongs unless you also SELECT that, or sort the results by the ID.

There should be no noticeable difference in performance; SQLite is an embedded database without client/server communication overhead, and the query does not need to be parsed again if you use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

A "nice" solution is using the `IN`operator:

```
SELECT name from table where id in  (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the IN operator is syntactic sugar built for exactly this purpose..

```
SELECT name from table where id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6.....)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hoping that you are getting the list of ID's on which you have to perform a query for names as input temp table @InputIDTable,

```
 SELECT name from table WHERE ID IN (SELECT id from @InputIDTable)
```